# Will git-merge delete untracked files?

Tags: git, github, git-merge, git-push, git-pull

I am using git for my code.

In my local repo i have a deleted a large folder and committed(`git push`) to repo, and after that i logged in to server and done `git pull`, but i got the below message

```
.....
.....
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
Updating 12hgb51..e27d363
error: The following untracked working tree files would be removed by merge:
    request_log
    request_log
......
......
```

But i have some changed files/uncommited files/untracked files on server(which i need only on server and don't want to commit it), so if do `git merge` command all the unsaved files will be gone on server ?,

Actually why git showing this error message
How to avoid this error without loosing unsaved files ?

Comment: What was the folder that you deleted?  was the request_log folder in it?

Comment: yeah actually i have deleted the folder names as request_log

Comment: git is showing this error message because the folder that git merge is trying to delete contains files that were not committed.  Here is what you need to do.  Back up the folder.  Run the git merge.  then restore the folder.  that way the merge can complete, but you keep the files.

Answer (score 0):

You can try a:

```
git update-index --skip-worktree -- <file>
```

And see if that file gets ignored during the merge.
There is also:

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged -- <file>
```

But since your files are untracked, they wouldn't be concerned by the second command.